# Download all google results for given Query

Tags: code-golf

#### The Task

Write a program to take a query from STDIN and then download the first 20 search results of that query from [google](http://www.google.com) and save them in a folder named `Search` as `html` files. Or if google points to a non-html file (like PDF), save whatever it is. Type of results may depend on the programmer, but the first 20 results should be matched. Ads etc. can also be counted as results.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) ; shortest code wins.

Comment: You mean, retrieve the contents of whatever google points to? How should the files be named?

Comment: Yes, i mean the same. The files can be named anything.

Comment: Can we provide the radius of the earth in microns?

Comment: No, You have to use SI units. Edited question.

Comment: OK, I've already got two lines of my code: `require'net/http'` `require'nokogiri'`

Comment: You know that this probably violates googles TOS?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn how come? I can't find anything where Google forbids automated access or requires that the content be displayed to the browser.

Comment: Is the `.html` extension required, or only the file format?

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this as it stands, not including the pointless scaling of the scoring system. "Search results" is somewhat ambiguous given the number of types of search results that Google will now give in response to a query. The instruction to "save as HTML" files is somewhat odd: surely the idea should be to save whatever the resource is, and it might not be an HTML file.

Comment: True - what if Google points to a non-HTML?

Comment: Another issue is that, apparently, some servers don't like my user agent (and no, I'm not embedding a "real" user agent in my code)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn how come this is not a code golf? The score is proportional to the code length...

Comment: "objective criterion other than code size" = score.

Comment: @JanDvorak HTML extension is not required.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I edited the question.

Comment: What are we supposed to do if some results fail downloading? Die spectacularly? Shrug and move on? Fetch a replacement result? I'd most preferably die spectacularly

Comment: If a result fails, then you have to move on and get the others.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <del>260</del> 256 characters

```
require'net/http';require'nokogiri';i=0;`mkdir Search`;`cd Search`;N=Net::HTTP
Nokogiri::HTML.parse(N.get"www.google.cz","/search?"+URI.encode_www_form(q:gets,num:20)).css(".r a").each{|e|File.open("#{i+=1}",?w)<<N.get(URI e['href'][/q=(.*?)&/,1])rescue 0}
```

Note: when testing this multiple times, be sure to add `` `cd ..` `` between each test to reset the current working directory lest you end up with `whatever/Search/Search/Search/Search...`

If we are allowed to fail on first unsuccessful result, we can drop `rescue 0` at the end of the second line and save 8 characters.

if we may assume input is alphanumeric and a single word, we can skip encoding and shave off some more characters. (**235 chars** with error recovery, **227** without)

```
require'net/http';require'nokogiri';i=0;`mkdir Search`;`cd Search`;N=Net::HTTP
Nokogiri::HTML.parse(N.get"www.google.cz","/search?num=20&q="+gets).css(".r a").each{|e|File.open("#{i+=1}",?w)<<N.get(URI e['href'][/q=(.*?)&/,1])}
```

Comment: Wait, is `www.google.cz` not the czech google? You have to use the english google, `www.google.com`.

Comment: Who said I have to use the english domain for Google? Does the inline link in your question count as normative? They point to the same machines with the same behavior and search results. If `.com` isactually required, count my solution as 261 characters. (actually, 260. I'm going to post a one-character improvement once I get to desktop and test its correctness)

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: yes. Does it fail on Unix? Access rights? Unfortunately, I can't test on Linux.

Comment: No, the  `\`cd Search\`` is pointless: the backticks are starting a child process and the directory will be changed in that – which not affects the parent process, the `ruby` one.

Comment: @manatwork from my testing, it writes to the child directory on Windows. Should I change to `Dir.chdir` for Unix?

Comment: If you make it cross-platform by changing to `Dir.chdir`, then better edit your note too: the `cd ..` between runs is only needed on Windows. But if you are not making it cross-platform, then you can spare 3 characters by changing `mkdir Search` to `md Search`.

Answer (score 2):

### Bash

```
mkdir Search;cd Search;wget -U msie -rl 1 -e robots=off -d http://www.google.com http://www.google.com/search?q=`cat`&num=20
```

Because `wget` is the right way to do that.

Comment: wait, does this work if the user enters a search string containing `&`? Shouldn't you escape the user input?

Comment: Maybe I should.

Comment: Will you... probably not - too many extra characters.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr right.